# Updating my database in just one click but it has multiple dynamic input field values

Tags: php

This is my code when I display textfields based on the no. of data result from my query,

for example it display 6 textfields and the user change the values, when i click submit how can I submit values to php and update my database?

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<p ><input class ="tb8" type= "text" value="'.$round.'"  name="percent" id="percent'.$y.'" /><span class="currencyinput">%</span></p>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

this is my button:

```
<input  style="font-weight:bold" type="Submit" class="rad-button xsmall light flat"  name="Submit"  value="SAVE" id="start_button"/>
```

Comment: Get values from fields and put them into SQL-query, then execute query.

Comment: You need to submit these text inputs via form and generate a query with all  values being submitted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You write your query to update. Since, data you didn't provided completely.. my query is not complete.

```
<form method='POST' action='Submit.php'>
<?
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{?>
   <tr>
       <p>
        <input class ="tb8" type= "text" value="<?echo $round;?>"  name="percent[]" id="percent<?echo $y;?>" />
            <span class="currencyinput">%</span>
       </p>
   </tr>
<?}?>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

**Submit.php**

```
$TotalPercentBox=$sizeof($percent);
for($i=0;$i<$TotalPercentBox;$i++)
{
    $Percent=$percent[$i];

    //It will get incremented till condition fails. Now, you will have 6. 

    $Query="UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName='$Percent' WHERE (Some Condition)"

    //Execute Query Here... 

}
```

Comment: name="percent[]" Hey Danish this is not what he wanted, he asked how he will get all values of input fields in php, you are sending array with each input button to php

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan: You better read question properly. 

"for example it display 6 textfields and the user change the values, when i click submit how to update my database?"

Comment: Yeah. 6 textfields. I Agree. 6 textfields with same name. Have you checked this code in your desktop/laptop/tab Mr @MuhammadIrfan ?

Comment: same name but different ids

Comment: I mean no offense just trying to help as you are ok

Comment: Different IDs, its his problem. Not mine.. What he is going to do with ID is his problem.. No, I'm just asking.. have you tested my code in your desktop/laptop/tab.. Mr @MuhammadIrfan ??

Comment: and how exactly I can test?, its his problem to test and mark your answer right, if it is not correct then he should remove it

Comment: Exactly. Then, how you downvoted my answer Mr @MuhammadIrfan

Comment: It is not the matter of cracking jokes @MuhammadIrfan. Here, people spend their precious/important time to help someone. If you don't like the answer or want some editing.. give your comment.. rather than demoralizing the person.. Ok..

Comment: I am really sorry Danish I was not making joke but still I beg you forgiveness thanks

Comment: Tnx for the replies, when i try the code youve given  the only value i get is in last textfield